# How to use a Java 8 Lambda expression to convert a List of one type to a List of its subtype

Tags: java, lambda, casting, java-8

I can only seem to find how to do this in C# not Java.

I have a `List<TypeX>` but I know that every single element in that list is actually a subclass of `TypeX` Called `TypeY`.

How can I write a Lambda expression that accepts `List<TypeX>` and returns `List<TypeY>`?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: If I'm being honest no, I'm still picking up the Java's lambda syntax.

Comment: Are you trying to view the same instance in a different way (unsafe) or make a new list as in the 3 answers (so far)?

Comment: If you _know_ that every element is a `TypeY`, you can just cast the list unsafely, which is free at runtime: `(List<TypeY>) (List) listOfTypeX`.

Comment: I'm after a new list as the answers so far have suggested.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For my example, I will use the following classes:

```
class TypeX {}
class TypeY extends TypeX {}
```

Then I have a `List<TypeX>`:

```
final List<TypeX> xList = ...
```

All you need to do is use the a method reference to `TypeY.class.cast`:

```
final List<TypeY> yList = xList.stream()
                               .map(TypeY.class::cast)
                               .collect(toList());
```

You can also `filter()` to exclude items that will cause an error:

```
final List<TypeY> yList = xList.stream()
                               .filter(TypeY.class::isInstance)
                               .map(TypeY.class::cast)
                               .collect(toList());
```

---

Examples use:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
```

Comment: I'm going to accept this as the correct answer because of the filter to exclude errors, but I'd suggest either mentioning the Static import for Collectors or changing the answer to Collectors.toList().

Comment: Thanks for this answer!

Answer (score 7):

Projecting in Java is done using the [`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) method:

```
List<TypeY> res = listTypeX
    .stream()
    .map((x) -> (TypeY)x)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 4):

Just all `map` with a lambda that casts the elements:

```
List<TypeX> list = ...;
List<TypeY> castList = 
    list.stream().map(x -> (TypeY)x).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `selectInstancesOf()` from [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/):

```
MutableList<TypeX> xList = Lists.mutable.empty();
MutableList<TypeY> yList = xList.selectInstancesOf(TypeY.class);
```

If you can't change xList from `List`:

```
List<TypeX> xList = Lists.mutable.empty();
List<TypeY> yList = ListAdapter.adapt(xList).selectInstancesOf(TypeY.class);
```

Note: I am a contributor to Eclipse Collections.